# tkinter listbox вернуть текст из выбранного элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Эта функция вернёт порядковый номер элемента в `listbox`:

```
def get_item_index(event):
   index = event.widget.curselection()
   print(int(index[0] + 1))
```

Есть ли возможность вернуть текст выбранного элемента?

Comment: Не "вернет", а напечатает в стандартный вывод!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

def onselect(evt):
    w = evt.widget
    i = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(i)
    print(value)


root = tk.Tk()

lb = tk.Listbox(root)
lb.insert(1, 'Python')
lb.insert(2, 'Perl')
lb.insert(3, 'C')
lb.insert(4, 'PHP')
lb.insert(5, 'JSP')
lb.insert(6, 'Ruby')

lb.pack()
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

root.mainloop()
```